# Ruby on rails 3 link_to controller and action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, action, link-to

I know this is probably a pretty simple concept. I am trying to create a link to a controller and action. For example I have a link in my layout file to update a record when a link is clicked, so I need to be able to link to the controller and action. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You use link_to to link to an action on a controller.  You need to provide more information to get the full answer.  Could you provide the name of your controller and the action you require?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
link_to "Label", :controller => :my_controller, :action => :index
```

See [url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for).

Comment: also often it is not bad idea to set `:method` if it is different from `:get`

Answer (score 11):

Also with CSS:

```
<%= link_to "Purchase", { :controller => :transactions, :action => :purchase }, { class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg", style: "width: 100%;" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass params too then do

```
<%= link_to student.name,  controller: "users", action: "show", id: student.id, partial: "profile"  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 6:

```
 <%= button_to "SIGN IN", { controller: 'o_auth', action: :login }, { class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg", style: "width: 100%;", method: :get} %>
```