# How to delete / destroy user in rails app from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently watched the railscast episode [#250 Authentication from Scratch (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised) and I have the signup / login / logout actions working.  However I am working on creating an action to delete a user from the database, but I am currently experiencing some errors when I try to delete a user.

The *users_controller.rb* delete / destroy actions look like the following,

```
def delete
    # the below line calls the destroy method / action
    self.destroy
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    # @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    # User.find(parmas[:id]).destroy
    # the below line didn't delete the current user :(
    # @user = User.destroy
    redirect_to :controller=>'users', :action => 'new'
  end
```

The error message I'm getting in the browser when I try to delete a user looks like the following.

[image]

The page that contains the delete link looks like the following, *index.html.erb*

```
<h1>Welcome 
    <% if current_user %>
        <%= current_user.email %>
    <% end %>
</h1>

<p>You have <%= current_user.credit %> credits.</p>

<!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607155/ -->
<%= link_to('Delete your account', :controller => 'users', :action => 'destroy') %>
```

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # the below generated route is not necessary
  # get 'sessions/new'

  # delete user route
  #get 'delete' => 'users#delete'

  # shortened routes, per railscast comment
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  # get 'signup', to: 'users#new', :as 'signup'
  # get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', :as 'login'
  # get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', :as 'logout'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  root to: 'users#new'

  # get 'users/new'

  # the below line specifies JSON as the default API format
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stands to reason you're getting a NoMethodError, since you've never set the `@user` variable, that line is commented out:

```
 def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    # @user = User.find(params[:id]) <-- Commenting out this line was your problem
    @user.destroy
```

Changing to

```
 def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
```

You should be good to go.

EDIT: one thing you'd probably want to do is change from using the old style of link_to, specifying the controller and action, and change to the new style, using [route helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers).  In this case, you'd use, i believe, `link_to 'Delete your account', current_user, :method => :delete`, but you can check by running `rake routes`, where it will list the helpers available based on your routes.rb file.

Comment: Changed the above line in the `index.html.erb` to the following, `<%= link_to 'Delete your account', users_path, :method => :delete %>` but now I'm getting the following error, `No route matches [DELETE] "/users"`

Comment: what is the output of `rake routes`, specifically the parts related to users?

Comment: Added the parameter, and I'm getting the same error :/

Comment: Also I think it should be `users_path` not `user_path`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56907/discussion-between-chris-and-abmagil).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you should make things a bit simpler and start from the dummiest thing, that works. First of all, if you use your controller as a resource, there would not be a delete action there, only destroy.

```
def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to new_user_path
end
```

P.S. once again, I assume that you have set `resources :users` in your `routes.rb`.
If you have a bunch of `get|post|put|delete` routes instead, just make sure you point the redirect correctly.

Comment: I modified my question for clarity.  I also rewrote my destroy action as you described, but I'm still getting an error.

No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}

Comment: please post your `routes.rb` file

Comment: posted the `routes.rb` file